# Load test and RPS in NBomber

Tags: .net-core, load-testing

I am trying to load test a Kafka instance on one of our servers.
Here is the code that does it using NBomber:

```
public static void Run()
{
    var testScenario = NBomber.CSharp.Step.Create("testScenario",
        
        async context =>
    {
        try
        {
            // The testData is a string variable that reads contents from a text file in the Init method.
            var kafkaObject = new KafkaObject { Topic = TestTopic, Message =testData };
            SampleKafkaFlow sampleKafkaFlow = new SampleKafkaFlow();
            var response = await sampleKafkaFlow.SendMessageToKafka(kafkaObject);
            return Response.Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Response.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    });

    var scenario = ScenarioBuilder.CreateScenario("scenario", testScenario)
        .WithoutWarmUp()
        .WithInit(Init)
    .WithLoadSimulations(new[]
        {
            Simulation.InjectPerSec(rate: 100, during: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3))
        });

    NBomber.CSharp.NBomberRunner
        .RegisterScenarios(scenario)
        .WithReportFileName($"testScenario-Report-{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss")}")
        .WithReportFolder("test_reports")
        .WithReportFormats(ReportFormat.Html)
        .Run();
}
```

My laptop configuration:

Core i5 10th Gen with 16 Gb RAM, running Windows 10.

At the time of running the load test only VS 2022 was running.

Now I assumed that at 100 RPS it would generate a total of 18k requests for 3 minutes of execution time. The report says different - while it did run for a total of 3 minutes there were only 2057 total requests!

[image: NBomber Report]

What am I missing here?

How do I get to doing a load test with a higher RPS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a issue with NBomber itself https://github.com/PragmaticFlow/NBomber/issues/488

Also check nbomber log – it could contain a lot of

```
Error: step unhandled exception: One or more errors occurred. (Too many open files in system
```

or another errors that indicate that OS limits your load test